# Sum 2 number with textbox / Laravel Php

Tags: php, html, laravel, visual-studio-code, echo

I have shared the MVC structure below. I can't understand why I am getting this error:

> Error: Undefined variable $sum

Controller:

```
public function get_form(){
    return view('form');
}

public function post_form(Request $request){
    $first=$request->first;
    $second=$request->second;
    $sum=$first + $second;
    return view('form')->with('sum',$sum);
}
```

Web.php:

```
Route::get('/form', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@get_form');
Route::post('/form', 'App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@post_form');
```

form.blade.php:

```
    {{ $sum }}
<html>
    <?php
    $sum=0;
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <input type="text" name="first"> 
        <input type="text" name="second"> 
        <input type="submit"> 
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Your code is text, please include it as text. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: First your HTML is view and there is no any `sum` param pass to view. and its given an error when first time page view

Comment: How can i fix that @BhargavChudasama

Comment: ı shared error image and text you can check again please @ADyson

Comment: Your code is all still from pictures

Comment: @AleynaŞenozan please check the anwser

Comment: I am sorry I understand now and fixed it @ADyson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ERROR: Undefined variable $sum
```

It's throwing that error because initially *before* the summation HTTP request is made, the View's rendered `$sum` variable is undefined.

It *only* gets defined on the second View render session after the input fields have been filled and a `form` submission has been made.

##### Solution

In your blade View.

```
{{$sum ?? 0}}
```

##### Adendum

Remove the source code below from your blade View file as well.

```php
<?php
$sum = 0;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this code

```
public function get_form(){
    $sum = 0;
    return view('form', compact('sum'));
}
```

define `$sum` param and pass to view to avoid the `undefined $sum` error

Comment: it doesnt work. It always says 0 on the screen.Will I delete the return on the post?

Comment: remove `$sum = 0` from `blade` file. it always 0 when page load